# unix second into postgres timestamp using php pg_query_params

Tags: php, postgresql, unix-timestamp, pg-query

I want to insert a unix timestamp value into a postgres timestamp column, using the PHP pg_query_params method, but get stuck.

Here's the incomplete code:

```
$con = pg_connect(...);
$stmt = 'INSERT INTO my_table (submitted) VALUES ($1)';
$ts = 1479939387;
$values = [translate_timestamp_into_sth_postgres_accepts($ts)];
$res = pg_query_params($con, $stmt, $values);
```

Q: how to transform the unix seconds value to sth. postgres accepts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function [`to_timestamp(double precision)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE):

```
select to_timestamp(1479939387) at time zone 'utc' as tstamp;

       tstamp        
---------------------
 2016-11-23 22:16:27
(1 row)
```

Your code may look like this (using default time zone):

```
$con = pg_connect(...);
$stmt = 'INSERT INTO my_table (submitted) VALUES (to_timestamp($1))';
$ts = 1479939387;
$res = pg_query_params($con, $stmt, $ts);
```

Comment: this is it! Thanks for the answer - and sorry for the delay.